# web2py - Display list of objects in grid

Tags: python, web2py

I am developing a web2py application(APP1) which works on the data which it gets from another web2py application(APP2).
We do not have access to the database of APP2, we access their data through jsonrpc web services exposed by APP2.
Now, there is an API(get_objects) of APP2 which gives us a list of certain type of objects. APP2 internally fetches this data from its database and convert it to a list of specific type of objects.
I want it to be displayed in a table with sorting and paging capabilities. 
Can I use web2py's SQLFORM.grid to achieve this?
Please suggest me any solution.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer by given by Massimo on google groups. I am sharing it here as given below:

You cannot unless you first load the data in a database. You can use a temporary in memory database like this:

```
fields = [Field('one'), Field('two'), Field('three'), ...]

temp_db = cache.ram('tmp_db',lambda: DAL('sqlite:memory').define_table('mytable',*fields)._db, None)

temp_db.mytable.truncate()

temp_db.mytable.insert(....)

form = SQLFORM.grid(temp_db.mytable)
```